# SQl trigger after insert error

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert

I'm trying to update/insert a value after I inserted a new row into my SQL table. I'm using a trigger to accomplish this but I get an error which I do understand what it means but I don't know how to fix it. I was under the impression that I could get the inserted row from the inserted table based on the @id I declared, that part seems to work but why do I get the error that I'm not allowed to enter a  NULL value into my "invoicenumber" field (I know it's the PK but I don't wont to enter anything into this field (it's already filled with correct data from the insert itself).

So, can anyone explain to me what I did wrong?

The table I used:

table delivery_invoice

```
id - int
invoicenumber(PK) - varchar(50)
amount6 - money
amount21 - money
distributor - int
payed - char(3)
deliverycosts - money
deliverydate - datetime
deliverytime - datetime
VATamount6 - calculated field
VATamount21 - calculated field
VATamountdelivery - int
```

The trigger I used

```
USE TestDelivery
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      James
-- Create date: 11-08-2017
-- Description: change VATamountdelivery field after a new row is inserted
-- =============================================
CREATE TRIGGER trgVATAmountDelivery
ON  dbo.delivery_invoice 
AFTER INSERT    
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @id int
Declare @amount money
Declare @invoice varchar(50)
Select @id = id from inserted
Select @amount = VATamount21 from inserted

IF @amount > 0
insert into dbo.delivery_invoice(VATamountdelivery)
    values(21)
    else
insert into dbo.delivery_invoice(VATamountdelivery)
    values(6) 

END
GO
```

And last but not least the error I got:

```
Error. Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'invoicenumber', table 
'TestDelivery delivery_invoice'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. 
The statement has been terminated.
```

Any help would be appriciated!
J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to insert a new row with the value.  I think you just want to change the value.

However, your trigger has other issues.  In particular, *never* assume that `inserted` contains only one row.  That is just a bug waiting to happen.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgVATAmountDelivery ON dbo.delivery_invoice 
AFTER INSERT    
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    update di
        set VATamountdelivery = (case when i.VATamount21 > 0 then 21 else 6 end)
        from dbo.delivery_invoice di join
             inserted i
             on i.id = di.id

END;
```

Comment: thanks, just tested the code and it works perfectly. I didn't realize that the insert table could hold more than one row but in this case, there will be only one row each time there is an insert so it should be fine. Thanks for the solution and the insight on the insert table